# Error occur during simple code of spring maven

Tags: spring

```
May 16, 2021 11:23:03 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'student1' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'studentId' of bean class [com.springcore.Student]: Bean property 'studentId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'student1' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'studentId' of bean class [com.springcore.Student]: Bean property 'studentId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1736)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.springcore.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'studentId' of bean class [com.springcore.Student]: Bean property 'studentId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:426)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1732)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Post the code which you have written

Comment: "_org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'studentId' of bean class [com.springcore.Student]: Bean property 'studentId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?_" seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because the lack of a setter method for your class properties (*studentId*) because spring context configurations use **setter methods** of your bean classes to set bean properties.

Or maybe the type of the property (*studentId*) doesn't match with the type of setter method parameter.

If I you add your class *Student*, i would be able to help better.